# Interceptor binding doesn't work

Tags: java, cdi, interceptor

I have CDI interceptor class annotated with javax.interceptor.InterceptorBinding @LogBinding, defined as follows:

```
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
public @interface LogBinding {}
```

Then I use annotation on EJB bean:

```
@Alternative
@Stateless
@LogBinding 
public class FooService {

    @Asynchronous
    public fooMethod() {

    }
}
```

I invoke fooMethod from another bean. The problem is that interceptor isn't called. Everything works when I change @LogBinding annotation to @Interceptors({LogInterceptor.class}) on the FooService.
I don't know if it may have impact but FooService is market as @Alternative, because it's injected in other places as EJB bean, below is the producer field:

```
@Default
@Produces
@EJB
private FooService fooService;


@Interceptor
@LogBinding
@Priority(Interceptor.Priority.APPLICATION)
public class LogInterceptor {
  @AroundInvoke
    public Object invoke(final InvocationContext invocationContext) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("it works");
    }
}
```

Why it doesn't work?

Comment: Dummy's answer is probably the issue, but it would help to see your `LogInterceptor` class. Doesn't have to be the full thing, just the class and method declarations with their annotations.

Comment: I've added interceptor class

Comment: First of all, I will assume you have verified (outside of this bean) that the interceptor and Alternative bean both work the way you expect them to work. As for the cause of your troubles - I am not sure but think the real problem here is the `@Asynchronous` EJB annotation. This means EJB will take the execution to another thread which is something CDI does not know about/cannot handle and therefore the interceptor won't be notified. Try exploring that a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You also have to annotate your interceptor class with that binding in order for it to know which class to use as the interceptor

```
@LogBinding
@Interceptor
public class LogInterceptor {...}
```

Comment: I am already annotating interceptor with binding (see updated question), but it doesn't work

Comment: You should check this documentation and see if you have satisfied the requirements for session bean alternative http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/Alternative.html